# Working with lists can't seem to match week days with numbers

Tags: python

I'm trying to match the day of the week up with numbers using lists but i'm not sure how. For example I want it to know day 1 is monday, day 2 is tuesday, day 3 is wednesday, day 4 is thursday and day 5 is friday

I've tried multiple things with the lists but I can't seem to figure it out

This is what i'm trying to get it to look like:

```
Enter sales for day 1: 10.22 (User input)
Enter sales for day 2: 4.12 (User input)
Enter sales for day 3: 3.78 (User input)
Enter sales for day 4: 6.82 (User input)
Enter sales for day 5: 22.45 (User input)

Maximum sales was on Friday which is $22.45
Minimum sales was on Wednesday which is $3.78
Total weekly sales were $47.39
Average of the sales is $9.48
Sales too low for commission must earn more than $100
```

This is what I have so far:

```
print ("Sales Calculator Program")

print ('\n')


expenses = []
for day_number in range (1, 5 + 1):
    while True:
        user_input = float(input(f"Enter sales for day {day_number}\n> "))
        if user_input >= 0:
            expenses.append(user_input)
            break
        else:
            print(f"Amount may not be negative. Try again:")
days = ('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday')




print ('\n')       

finalExpenses = sum(expenses)
average = finalExpenses / 5
maxExpenses = max(expenses)
minExpenses = min(expenses)

if finalExpenses < 100:
    print( "Sales too low for commission must earn more than 100$")
elif finalExpenses < 250:
    print ( "You get a commission of 25$")
elif finalExpenses < 500:
    print ( "You get a commission of 30$")
else:
    print ( "You get a commission of 40$")




print ("Maximum sales on is $" +str(maxExpenses))
print ("Minimum sales is $" +str(minExpenses))
print ("Total weekly sales were $" +str(finalExpenses))
print ("Average of the sales is $" +str(average))
```

I have it all finished besides matching the day with the number and printing it as showed an the example.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

To make sure I understand the problem correctly -- you have two lists:

- `[10.22, 4.12, 3.78, 6.82, 22.45]`
- `['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday']`

and you want to match the numbers from the the first list to the days in the second.

What you want is the `list.index()` method:

```
maxExpenses = max(expenses)
index = expenses.index(maxExpenses)
day = days[index]
```

and then your `print()` can be:

```
print ("Maximum sales on ' + day + ' is $" +str(maxExpenses))
```

Comment: Okay, that makes sense i'm just very confused on where I can implement this in my current code to get it to function properly. I tried going off of this and I couldn't seem to get it

Comment: @KingDarmani:  Sorry, I misread the problem.  Solution is rewritten.

Comment: I got it working thank you! The only problem im having now is it says the correct minimum number but it says its on the wrong day for example I would type in a max number on day 3 (wednesday) and a min number on day 5 (friday) and it will say the max and min are both on wednesday for some reason

Comment: Take note that `.index()` returns the first element that matches, so if you have more than one instance of the same value, earliest day is returned.

Comment: @KingDarmani: Are you recalculating `index`?  Are you using the first value of `index` before you recalculate it?  You may want to have two: `min_index` and `max_index` so they don't get confused.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `argmax` and `argmin` function from `numpy` module:

```
import numpy as np
finalExpenses = sum(expenses)
average = finalExpenses / 5
maxExpensesDay = np.argmax(expenses)
minExpensesDay = np.argmin(expenses)

if finalExpenses < 100:
    print( "Sales too low for commission must earn more than 100$")
elif finalExpenses < 250:
    print ( "You get a commission of 25$")
elif finalExpenses < 500:
    print ( "You get a commission of 30$")
else:
    print ( "You get a commission of 40$")

print ("Maximum sales on " + days[maxExpensesDay] + " is $" +str(expenses[maxExpensesDay]))
print ("Minimum sales on " + days[minExpensesDay] + " is $" +str(expenses[minExpensesDay]))
print ("Total weekly sales were $" +str(finalExpenses))
print ("Average of the sales is $" +str(average))
```

Output:

```
Enter sales for day
>22.45
Enter sales for day
>3.78
Enter sales for day
>47.39
Enter sales for day
>9.48
Enter sales for day
>22.45


You get a commission of 25$
Maximum sales on Wednesday is $47.39
Minimum sales on Tuesday is $3.78
Total weekly sales were $105.55000000000001
Average of the sales is $21.110000000000003
```

Comment: I put that in and I get the error no module named numpy

Comment: Using `numpy` for this problem is killing a mosquito with a cannon.